# Android Java Added an ArrayList now program is running very slow

Tags: java, android

I added a Arraylist and is slowed down my code.
My original code looked something like this:

```
 //to draw the tiles
        for (int i = 0; i < bitmaps.length; i++) {

            for (int a = 0; a < bitmaps[i].length; a++) {

                if (bitmaps[i][a] != null) {

                    //to make sure tiles only get drawn on the screen
                    if(tileRect[i][a].left > RunMovement.getCurrentView() -25 && tileRect[i][a].left < RunMovement.getCurrentView() + screenWidth + 25) {


                        mCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmaps[i][a], null, tileRect[i][a], null);

                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

I needed to add a Arraylist to store different levels, so I changed it to this

```
 //for the new array levels
        for (int b = 0; b < levelTileList.size(); b++) {               

            //to draw the tiles

            for (int i = 0; i < levelTileList.get(b).length; i++) {



                for (int a = 0; a < levelTileList.get(b)[i].length; a++) {//hope this works



                    if (levelTileList.get(b)[i][a] != null) {



                        //to make sure tiles only get drawn on the screen

                        if (levelTileListRec.get(b)[i][a].left > RunMovement.getCurrentView() - 25 && levelTileListRec.get(b)[i][a].left < RunMovement.getCurrentView() + screenWidth + 25) {


                            //mCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmaps[i][a], null, tileRect[i][a], null);
                            mCanvas.drawBitmap(levelTileList.get(b)[i][a], null, levelTileListRec.get(b)[i][a], null);


                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The code works but my program slowed down drastically.
Can someone please tell me why, and if there's a way to fix it.

Comment: i don't think the problem is with a arraylist , you're doing reading and arraylist  are somewhat as fast arrays for reading , what i can see it there is one nested loop in the first one and two in the second one

Comment: @ Abhinax Chaughan at the moment there's only 1 element in the Arraylist, so they should run at about the same speed.

Comment: looks like there is an array inside all elements of arraylist which may be making it more slower, secondly how do you know the second one is more slower

Comment: in all arraylists can't be noticeably slower than array for reading if you try to do same things , trying running a loop , you will find it is true, arraylist are slower for writing only infact that also can be improved by using appropriate initial capacity and load factor

Comment: @ Abhinav Chauhan I know it's slower because there's frames per second drop,

Comment: Alright this is pretty weird. For about the first second it runs normally then it only drops. I have no idea what might cause this.

Answer (score 0):

Lists, in general, are data structures that are way slower than arrays, terms of initializing time and accessing time, just because the way they are implemented.

Comment: The reason I used arraylists is because I want to add and delete from it at will. Will it be faster to use normal arrays and just create and destroy the entire array as needed.(This will be done while the game is running)

Comment: that's the actual implementation of an ArrayList, unfortunately

Comment: Arraylist is not a linked list it implements RandomAccess interface despite the fact it implements List interface too it is actually a dynamic array inside something like you get from using malloc and calloc in c, so no arraylist are not slow for reading like linked list are they are as fast as arrays but for reading only.